# Async module.exports dependency in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I have two test files in Node.js that depend on each other. The first test runs some async work, and at the end exports an object with a UUID that the second test requires.

## test_1.js

```
'use strict';

# simulate some async work
setTimeout(() => {
    module.exports = {
        id: '83b50527-73a9-4926-8247-e37547f3da6d'
    };
}, 2000);
```

## test_2.js

```
'use strict';

const testOne = require('./test_1.js');
console.log(testOne);
```

The problem is since the `module.exports` is called async in the first test, in test two `console.log(testOne)` is just an empty object.

How can I make `test_2.js` wait until `test_1.js` is finished exporting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Promise to the rescue is one fashion for it.

**test_1.js**

```
module.exports = new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve({
    id: '83b50527-73a9-4926-8247-e37547f3da6d'
  }), 2000);
});
```

**test_2.js**

```
const testOne = require('./test_1.js');
testOne.then(uuid => console.log(uuid.id));
```

Carefully bear in mind that the same promise instance is returned each time *test_1.js* is imported. This effects how the promise instance shall be consumed.

Comment: so even if I comment out `testOne.then`, `setTimeout` fires anyway. This doesn't make any sense. And how can I pass parameters anyway?

Comment: I would not import a module without consuming it.

Comment: and how do i pass parameter? let's say delay time? thaks

Comment: Export from test1 a hugher order function instead which returns the promise. In test2, call the function with parameters and get the promise.

Comment: you don't need to return promise, you just export async function and await it